# Cardinalities of Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I must be missing something very simple here.

> **Problem:** Let $|G|=56$. Let H be a Sylow 7-subgroup of G, and suppose H is not a normal subgroup of G. What are the cardinalities of the Sylow 7-subgroups of G and the Sylow 2-subgroups of G?

**My attempt:** The cardinalities of the Sylow 7-subgroups in G can be either 56 or 8, and the cardinalities of the Sylow 2-subgroups in G can be either 28, 14, or 7. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of a Sylow $p$-subgroup is always a power of $p$.  In particular, it is the largest power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$.  Based on your guesses, you might be thinking of the *number of* Sylow $p$-subgroups.

In fact, the question sounds like it's asking for the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups and not their cardinalities.  The fact that $H$ is not normal in $G$ has no bearing on the cardinality of any Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

The number of 7 Sylow group cannot be 56 ( Why?) What else can it be?  Count the number of elements remaining after you use all the elements of order 7. The number of 2 sylow groups must be odd and divide 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to ask the number of Sylow $2$- and $7$-subgroups. The cardinalities are already determined by the order of $G$, as SMoore explained.

The third Sylow theorem states that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $n_p$ is the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, then $n_p \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} p)$ and $n_p \mid [G:P]$. So the number cannot be $|G|$ if $p \mid |G|$.

$H$ not being normal tells you that there is not just one Sylow $7$-subgroup. (Why?)

From this, try counting elements like Luis suggested.